# Selecting values which appear most frequently in order of frequency

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column from which I would like to return only distinct values, not matching certain criteria, in descending order of the most frequent value.

The column contains these records:

```
this 
those
that
dog
these
here
there
cat
dog
hamster
hamster
there
blah
here
blah
blah
dog
```

So I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(rcolumn)
FROM otable
WHERE reason != 'this'
AND reason != 'that'
AND reason != 'those'
AND reason != 'these'
AND reason != 'them'
AND reason != 'here'
AND reason != 'there'
AND reason != 'in between'
AND reason != 'all over'
AND reason != 'something'
AND reason != 'something else'
AND reason != 'anywhere'
AND reason != 'anywhere else'
```

Which will return:

```
blah
cats
hamsters
dogs
```

But I would like it to return:

```
blah
dogs
hamsters
cats
```

In that order, as blah appears most in the table, then dogs, then hamsters, then cats.

Comment: SELECT column ... GROUP BY column ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return stuff in order of frequency you'll need to `GROUP BY` the values:

```
SELECT   rcolumn
FROM     otable
-- WHERE stuff
GROUP BY rcolumn;
```

This should give basically the same answer as what you have. You can then easily count the incidence of each row and sort:

```
SELECT   rcolumn, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM     otable
GROUP BY rcolumn
ORDER BY frequency DESC;
```

If you'd prefer not to see the calculated frequency column in the results then you can just order by this straight away:

```
SELECT   rcolumn
FROM     otable
GROUP BY rcolumn
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

In general when using a `GROUP BY` clause be careful to only select either:

- columns you're grouping by
- results of aggregate functions

Most RDBMSes will catch this as an error, but MySQL will just pick a random row and return you that data.

Finally for added clarity, why not change your long `WHERE` clause into something more elegant:

```
WHERE rcolumn NOT IN
    ('this'
    ,'that'
    ,'those'
    -- ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `ORDER BY COUNT(rcolumn) DESC` at the end of your statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT rcolumn
FROM otable
WHERE reason != 'this'
AND reason != 'that'
AND reason != 'those'
AND reason != 'these'
AND reason != 'them'
AND reason != 'here'
AND reason != 'there'
AND reason != 'in between'
AND reason != 'all over'
AND reason != 'something'
AND reason != 'something else'
AND reason != 'anywhere'
AND reason != 'anywhere else'
ORDER BY COUNT(rcolumn) DESC
;
```